# How to configure ninject to inject different dependency types into the same class?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I've run into what I believe must be a common dependency injection-related problem.  I'm having trouble finding relevant examples, and I do not like the best solution I've been able to come up with.

```
public class WasherDryerFolderSystem : ILaundrySystem
{
    private IWasher _washer;
    private IDryer _dryer;
    private IFolder _folder;

    public WasherDryerFolderSystem(IWasher washer, IDryer dryer, IFolder folder)
    {...}

    public void DoLaundry()
    {
        _washer.Wash();
        _dryer.Dry();
        _folder.Fold();
    }
}


public class HandWasher : IWasher {...}
public class MachineWasher : IWasher {...}

public class HandDryer : IDryer {...}
public class MachineDryer : IDryer {...}

public class HandFolder : IFolder {...}
public class MachineFolder : IFolder {...}
```

Now in the main app I have something like

```
var laundrySystem = _kernel.Get<ILaundrySystem>(someUserInput);
```

What is a good way to configure the bindings required for something like this?  Here's what I've been able to come up with thus far (that I don't like):

```
Bind<ILaundrySystem>().To<WasherDryerFolderSystem>()
    .Named(MACHINEWASH_HANDDRY_HANDFOLD)
    .WithConstructorArgument("washer", new MachineWasher())
    .WithConstructorArgument("dryer", new HandDryer())
    .WithConstructorArgument("folder", new HandFolder());
```

At first I didn't think this looked too bad, but when Washers and Dryers and Folders all have their own dependencies, this quickly gets ugly.

This feels to me like it should be a common problem, but I'm not finding anything that's much help.  Do I have something designed incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a factory pattern:

```cs
public interface ILaundrySystemFactory
{
    ILaundrySystem  Create(string someUserInput);
}

public class LaundrySystemFactory : ILaundrySystemFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public LaundrySystemFactory(IKernel kernel){
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public ILaundrySystem Create(string someUserInput)
    {
        if(someUserInput){
            var washer = _kernel.Get<MachineWasher>();
            var dryer = _kernel.Get<HandDryer>();
            var folder = _kernel.Get<HandFolder>();
        } else {            
            var washer = _kernel.Get<DifferentWasher>();
            var dryer = _kernel.Get<DifferentDryer>();
            var folder = _kernel.Get<DifferentFolder>();
        }
        return new WasherDryerFolderSystem(washer, dryer, folder);
    }
}
```

and then simply

```cs
private readonly ILaundrySystemFactory  _laundrySystemFactory;

ctor(ILaundrySystemFactory laundrySystemFactory){
    _laundrySystemFactory = laundrySystemFactory;
}

public UserInputMethod(string someUserInput)
{
    var loundrySystem = laundrySystemFactory.Create(someUserInput);
    var loundry = loundrySystem.DoLaundry();
}
```

bindings:

```cs
Bind<ILaundrySystemFactory>().To<LaundrySystemFactory>();
```

(some DI containers might also need something like:)

```cs
Bind<MachineWasher>().To<MachineWasher>();
```

Comment: I need to inject a different washer/dryer/folder into the WasherDryerFolderSystem based on user input, and unless I'm missing something, your solution would always inject a MachineWasher into IWasher, a HandDryer into IDryer, and a HandFolder into IFolder.  I need those to change.

Answer (score 0):

Make a concrete classes with concrete parameters you need, put them as dependencies of strategy which will use them based on user input. Next instantiate them all with SINGLE call for a resolution root class. OFC Strategy can be the resolution root itself but it also can be a dependency of different resoultion root. Example:

```
//DoLaundry based on user input
public class WasherDryerFolderSystemStrategy
{
    ctor(MachineWashingHandDringHandFoldingSystem first,
       MachineWashingHandDringHandFoldingSystem second,
       HandWashingHandDringHandFoldingWithBreakfastSystem third) { ... }

    public void DoLaundry(int userInput)
    {
       if(userInput == 1)
           first.DoLaundry();
       if(userInput == 2)
           second.DoLaundry();
       if(userInput == 3)
           third.DoLaundry();
    }
}

// MACHINEWASH_HANDDRY_HANDFOLD
public class MachineWashingHandDringHandFoldingSystem : WasherDryerFolderSystem
{
    public MachineWashingHandDringHandFoldingSystem
        (MachineWasher machineWasher, HandDryer handDryer, HandFolder handFolder) :
        base(machineWasher, handDryer, handFolder)
    {
    }
}

// HANDWASH_HANDDRY_HANDNOFOLD
public class HandWashingHandDringHandFoldingSystem : WasherDryerFolderSystem
{
    public MachineWashingHandDringHandFoldingSystem
        (HandWasher machineWasher, HandDryer handDryer, HandFolder handFolder) :
        base(machineWasher, handDryer, handFolder)
    {
    }
}

// HANDWASH_HANDDRY_HANDNOFOLD_WITHBREAKFAST
public class HandWashingHandDringHandFoldingWithBreakfastSystem : WasherDryerFolderSystem
{
   private readonly BreakfastMaker breakfastMaker

   public MachineWashingHandDringHandFoldingSystem
       (HandWasher machineWasher, HandDryer handDryer, HandFolder handFolder, BreakfastMaker brekfastMaker) :
        base(machineWasher, handDryer, handFolder)
    {
        this.breakfastMaker = breakfastMaker
    }

    public overide void DoLaundry()
    {
        base.DoLaundry();
        brekfastMaker.AndMakeChipBreakAsWell();
    }
}
```

Please note that the implementation above does not require any Ninject configuration. Ninject will autobind everything ToSelf() with the first use (as long as it is not an interface).

In general as long as you do not need some sort of composite/bulk operations with with multiple implementations, than you should avoid interface bindings (and interfaces at all). Composite like operation example:

```
// original WasherDryerFolderSystem refactored
public class WasherDryerFolderSystem
{
    private IEnumerable<IWasher> washers;
    private IEnumerable<IDryer> dryers;
    private IEnumerable<IFolder> folders;

    public WasherDryerFolderSystem(
        IWasher[] washers, IDryer[] dryers, IFolder[] folders)
    {
        this.washers = washers;
        this.dryers = dryers;
        this.folders = folders;
    }

    // all inclusive
    public virtual void DoLaundry()
    {
        foreach (var washer in washers)
            washer.Wash();

        foreach (var dryer in dryers)
            dryer.Dry();

        foreach (var folder in folders)
            folder.Fold();
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.